# Groupby based on value in previous row

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a column with a list of values like so:

```
100
200
300
500
600
650
1000
```

I want to do a `Groupby` (or a similar efficient construct) to get batches of rows where the value of each row is within `100` of the last row.

In that case the batches produced from the example above would be

`100, 200, 300`,

`500, 600, 650`

`1000`

Is this possible to do in Pandas? Since Pandas attempts to allow for SQL-like queries, I am guessing that it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an approach similar to that described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358567/finding-consecutive-segments-in-a-pandas-data-frame).  It's basically a three-step process:

1. Use `shift` to compute the inter-row criterion that you want to distinguish.
2. Use `cumsum` to sum this criterion to create a new Series with separate "blocks" of a single value for each group.
3. Group on this new Series.

Here is an example:

```
>>> x = pandas.Series([100, 200, 300, 500, 600, 650, 1000, 900, 750])
>>> x.groupby(((x - x.shift()).abs() > 100).cumsum()).apply(list)
0    [100, 200, 300]
1    [500, 600, 650]
2        [1000, 900]
3              [750]
dtype: object
```

Note that I used the criterion `> 100`, which is the opposite of the `<= 100` criterion you mentioned.  With this approach, you need to use the criterion for *separating* groups, not the criterion for joining them, so you have to use the negation of your grouping criterion.