# Interpolate (or extrapolate) only small gaps in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, extrapolation

I have a pandas DataFrame with time as index (1 min Freq) and several columns worth of data. Sometimes the data contains NaN. If so, I want to interpolate only if the gap is not longer than 5 Minutes. In this case this would be a maximum of 5 consecutive NaNs. The data may look like this (several test cases, which show the problems):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(2014,2,21,14,50)
data = pd.DataFrame(index=[start + timedelta(minutes=1*x) for x in range(0, 8)],
                         data={'a': [123.5, np.NaN, 136.3, 164.3, 213.0, 164.3, 213.0, 221.1],
                               'b': [433.5, 523.2, 536.3, 464.3, 413.0, 164.3, 213.0, 221.1],
                               'c': [123.5, 132.3, 136.3, 164.3] + [np.NaN]*4,
                               'd': [np.NaN]*8,
                               'e': [np.NaN]*7 + [2330.3],
                               'f': [np.NaN]*4 + [2763.0, 2142.3, 2127.3, 2330.3],
                               'g': [2330.3] + [np.NaN]*7,
                               'h': [2330.3] + [np.NaN]*6 + [2777.7]})
```

It reads like this:

```
In [147]: data
Out[147]: 
                         a      b      c   d       e       f       g       h
2014-02-21 14:50:00  123.5  433.5  123.5 NaN     NaN     NaN  2330.3  2330.3
2014-02-21 14:51:00    NaN  523.2  132.3 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:52:00  136.3  536.3  136.3 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:53:00  164.3  464.3  164.3 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:54:00  213.0  413.0    NaN NaN     NaN  2763.0     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:55:00  164.3  164.3    NaN NaN     NaN  2142.3     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:56:00  213.0  213.0    NaN NaN     NaN  2127.3     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:57:00  221.1  221.1    NaN NaN  2330.3  2330.3     NaN  2777.7
```

I am aware of `data.interpolate()` but it has several flaws, as it produces this result, which is good for the columns a-e, but for the columns f-h it fails for different reasons::

```
                         a      b      c   d       e       f       g  \
2014-02-21 14:50:00  123.5  433.5  123.5 NaN     NaN     NaN  2330.3   
2014-02-21 14:51:00  129.9  523.2  132.3 NaN     NaN     NaN  2330.3   
2014-02-21 14:52:00  136.3  536.3  136.3 NaN     NaN     NaN  2330.3   
2014-02-21 14:53:00  164.3  464.3  164.3 NaN     NaN     NaN  2330.3   
2014-02-21 14:54:00  213.0  413.0  164.3 NaN     NaN  2763.0  2330.3   
2014-02-21 14:55:00  164.3  164.3  164.3 NaN     NaN  2142.3  2330.3   
2014-02-21 14:56:00  213.0  213.0  164.3 NaN     NaN  2127.3  2330.3   
2014-02-21 14:57:00  221.1  221.1  164.3 NaN  2330.3  2330.3  2330.3   

                               h  
2014-02-21 14:50:00  2330.300000  
2014-02-21 14:51:00  2394.214286  
2014-02-21 14:52:00  2458.128571  
2014-02-21 14:53:00  2522.042857  
2014-02-21 14:54:00  2585.957143  
2014-02-21 14:55:00  2649.871429  
2014-02-21 14:56:00  2713.785714  
2014-02-21 14:57:00  2777.700000
```

f) The gap consists of 4 minutes worth of NaNs in the beginning, they should be replaced by that value 2763.0 (i.e. extrapolating backwards in time)

g) The gap is longer than 5 minutes but still it gets extrapolated

h) The gap is longer than 5 minutes but still the gap is interpolated.

I understand those reasons, of course I nowhere specified that it should not interpolate longer gaps than 5 minutes. I understand that `interpolate` only extrapolates forward in time, but I want it to also extrapolate backward in time. Is there any known methods I can use for my problem, without reinventing the wheel?

Edit:
The method `data.interpolate` accepts the input parameter `limit`, which defines the maximum number of consecutive NaNs to be substituted by interpolation. But this still interpolates up to the limit, but I want to go on with all NaNs in that case.

Comment: You could use `bfill()` backward-fill method after interpolation?

Comment: @JohnGalt ``bfill()`` looks good for after the interpolation. Sadly it encounters the same problem for longer gaps than 5 minutes, as it simlpy fills them.

Comment: What are you expecting then? If it has only one value, it cannot interpolate values.

Comment: @JohnGalt I am expecting it to extrapolate, but only if the gap is not longer than 5 minutes, i.e. 5 consecutive NaNs. I.e. ``bfill`` fixes case f, but it does not fix case g.

Comment: @JohnE Yep, i just added my awareness of ``limit``. It almost gets the job done, as it stops interpolating after the 5th value. But it should not interpolate at all, if the gap is longer than the limit of 5.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So here is a mask that ought to solve the problem.  Just `interpolate` and then apply the mask to reset appropriate values to NaN.  Honestly, this was a bit more work than I realized it would be because I had to loop through each column but then groupby didn't quite work without me providing some dummy columns like 'ones'.

Anyway, I can explain if anything is unclear but really only a couple of the lines are somewhat hard to understand.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499049/testing-subsequent-values-in-a-dataframe/29500132#29500132) for a little bit more of an explanation of the trick on the `df['new']` line or just print out individual lines to better see what is going on.

```
mask = data.copy()
for i in list('abcdefgh'):
    df = pd.DataFrame( data[i] )
    df['new'] = ((df.notnull() != df.shift().notnull()).cumsum())
    df['ones'] = 1
    mask[i] = (df.groupby('new')['ones'].transform('count') < 5) | data[i].notnull()

In [7]: data
Out[7]: 
                         a      b      c   d       e       f       g       h
2014-02-21 14:50:00  123.5  433.5  123.5 NaN     NaN     NaN  2330.3  2330.3
2014-02-21 14:51:00    NaN  523.2  132.3 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:52:00  136.3  536.3  136.3 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:53:00  164.3  464.3  164.3 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:54:00  213.0  413.0    NaN NaN     NaN  2763.0     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:55:00  164.3  164.3    NaN NaN     NaN  2142.3     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:56:00  213.0  213.0    NaN NaN     NaN  2127.3     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:57:00  221.1  221.1    NaN NaN  2330.3  2330.3     NaN  2777.7

In [8]: mask
Out[8]: 
                        a     b     c      d      e     f      g      h
2014-02-21 14:50:00  True  True  True  False  False  True   True   True
2014-02-21 14:51:00  True  True  True  False  False  True  False  False
2014-02-21 14:52:00  True  True  True  False  False  True  False  False
2014-02-21 14:53:00  True  True  True  False  False  True  False  False
2014-02-21 14:54:00  True  True  True  False  False  True  False  False
2014-02-21 14:55:00  True  True  True  False  False  True  False  False
2014-02-21 14:56:00  True  True  True  False  False  True  False  False
2014-02-21 14:57:00  True  True  True  False   True  True  False   True
```

It's easy from there if you don't do anything fancier with respect to extrapolation:

```
In [9]: data.interpolate().bfill()[mask]
Out[9]: 
                         a      b      c   d       e       f       g       h
2014-02-21 14:50:00  123.5  433.5  123.5 NaN     NaN  2763.0  2330.3  2330.3
2014-02-21 14:51:00  129.9  523.2  132.3 NaN     NaN  2763.0     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:52:00  136.3  536.3  136.3 NaN     NaN  2763.0     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:53:00  164.3  464.3  164.3 NaN     NaN  2763.0     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:54:00  213.0  413.0  164.3 NaN     NaN  2763.0     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:55:00  164.3  164.3  164.3 NaN     NaN  2142.3     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:56:00  213.0  213.0  164.3 NaN     NaN  2127.3     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:57:00  221.1  221.1  164.3 NaN  2330.3  2330.3     NaN  2777.7
```

**Edit to add:**  Here's a faster (about 2x on this sample data) and slightly simpler way, by moving some stuff outside of the loop:

```
mask = data.copy()
grp = ((mask.notnull() != mask.shift().notnull()).cumsum())
grp['ones'] = 1
for i in list('abcdefgh'):
    mask[i] = (grp.groupby(i)['ones'].transform('count') < 5) | data[i].notnull()
```

Comment: Hey JohnE, very nice idea to interpolate/bfill for all values and simply just use the results at previously defined positions. Runtime is an issue, there are cases with approx ~1000 columns. I will check for the runtime and see if i can create the mask more efficiently with some hard thinking if needed.

Comment: FYI: I took your idea, adding cases, as the case of some NaNs, which should be interpolated, is quite rare: ``if df.isnull().all()`` - the mask is all False, ``elif df.isnull().any()`` do the groubpy-stuff you provided and for ``else`` set the mask to all True. Also it is somewhat faster when not running the loop but putting the mask creation in a method and feeding ``data.apply()`` with it.

Comment: OK, to be honest I was just happy when I got that code to work at all!  I didn't spend any time optimizing it so I'm sure you can improve it.  I did just add an edit that helps merely by moving some code outside of the loop, but sounds like you already have some good ideas to increase performance.  FWIW, I suspect the groupby/transform is now taking up most of the time, but don't see an obvious way around that.

Comment: Thanks for this! I think where you have "< 5" it should be "<= 5", if that's the interpolation limit.

Answer (score 4):

I had to solve a similar problem and came up with a `numpy` based solution before I found the answer above. Since my code is approx. ten times faster, I provide it here for it to be useful for somebody in the future. It handles NaNs at the end of the series differently than [the solution of JohnE above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30538371/356463). If a series ends with NaNs it flags this last gap as invalid.

Here is the code:

```py
def bfill_nan(arr):
    """ Backward-fill NaNs """
    mask = np.isnan(arr)
    idx = np.where(~mask, np.arange(mask.shape[0]), mask.shape[0]-1)
    idx = np.minimum.accumulate(idx[::-1], axis=0)[::-1]
    out = arr[idx]
    return out

def calc_mask(arr, maxgap):
    """ Mask NaN gaps longer than `maxgap` """
    isnan = np.isnan(arr)
    cumsum = np.cumsum(isnan).astype('float')
    diff = np.zeros_like(arr)
    diff[~isnan] = np.diff(cumsum[~isnan], prepend=0)
    diff[isnan] = np.nan
    diff = bfill_nan(diff)
    return (diff < maxgap) | ~isnan


mask = data.copy()

for column_name in data:
    x = data[column_name].values
    mask[column_name] = calc_mask(x, 5)

print('data:')
print(data)

print('\nmask:')
print mask
```

Output:

```
data:
                         a      b      c   d       e       f       g       h
2014-02-21 14:50:00  123.5  433.5  123.5 NaN     NaN     NaN  2330.3  2330.3
2014-02-21 14:51:00    NaN  523.2  132.3 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:52:00  136.3  536.3  136.3 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:53:00  164.3  464.3  164.3 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:54:00  213.0  413.0    NaN NaN     NaN  2763.0     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:55:00  164.3  164.3    NaN NaN     NaN  2142.3     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:56:00  213.0  213.0    NaN NaN     NaN  2127.3     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:57:00  221.1  221.1    NaN NaN  2330.3  2330.3     NaN  2777.7

mask:
                        a     b      c      d      e     f      g      h
2014-02-21 14:50:00  True  True   True  False  False  True   True   True
2014-02-21 14:51:00  True  True   True  False  False  True  False  False
2014-02-21 14:52:00  True  True   True  False  False  True  False  False
2014-02-21 14:53:00  True  True   True  False  False  True  False  False
2014-02-21 14:54:00  True  True  False  False  False  True  False  False
2014-02-21 14:55:00  True  True  False  False  False  True  False  False
2014-02-21 14:56:00  True  True  False  False  False  True  False  False
2014-02-21 14:57:00  True  True  False  False   True  True  False   True
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the `interpolate` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) `limit_area` as used below is new in version 0.23.0. I'm not sure, if this is the desired output for columns e and g, as you haven't specified the desired output in detail.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

start = datetime(2014,2,21,14,50)
df = data = pd.DataFrame(index=[start + timedelta(minutes=1*x) for x in range(0, 8)],
                         data={'a': [123.5, np.NaN, 136.3, 164.3, 213.0, 164.3, 213.0, 221.1],
                               'b': [433.5, 523.2, 536.3, 464.3, 413.0, 164.3, 213.0, 221.1],
                               'c': [123.5, 132.3, 136.3, 164.3] + [np.NaN]*4,
                               'd': [np.NaN]*8,
                               'e': [np.NaN]*7 + [2330.3],
                               'f': [np.NaN]*4 + [2763.0, 2142.3, 2127.3, 2330.3],
                               'g': [2330.3] + [np.NaN]*7,
                               'h': [2330.3] + [np.NaN]*6 + [2777.7]})

df.interpolate(
    limit=5,
    inplace=True,
    limit_direction='both',
    limit_area='outside',
    )

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                         a      b      c   d       e       f       g       h
2014-02-21 14:50:00  123.5  433.5  123.5 NaN     NaN  2763.0  2330.3  2330.3
2014-02-21 14:51:00    NaN  523.2  132.3 NaN     NaN  2763.0  2330.3     NaN
2014-02-21 14:52:00  136.3  536.3  136.3 NaN  2330.3  2763.0  2330.3     NaN
2014-02-21 14:53:00  164.3  464.3  164.3 NaN  2330.3  2763.0  2330.3     NaN
2014-02-21 14:54:00  213.0  413.0  164.3 NaN  2330.3  2763.0  2330.3     NaN
2014-02-21 14:55:00  164.3  164.3  164.3 NaN  2330.3  2142.3  2330.3     NaN
2014-02-21 14:56:00  213.0  213.0  164.3 NaN  2330.3  2127.3     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:57:00  221.1  221.1  164.3 NaN  2330.3  2330.3     NaN  2777.7
```

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and adapted @JohnE's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30538371/11052174) into a function (with some tweaks/improvements). I'm using Python 3.8, and I believe type hinting changed for 3.9, so you may have to adapt.

```py
from typing import Union

def fill_with_hard_limit(
        df_or_series: Union[pd.DataFrame, pd.Series], limit: int,
        fill_method='interpolate',
        **fill_method_kwargs) -> Union[pd.DataFrame, pd.Series]:
    """The fill methods from Pandas such as ``interpolate`` or ``bfill``
    will fill ``limit`` number of NaNs, even if the total number of
    consecutive NaNs is larger than ``limit``. This function instead
    does not fill any data when the number of consecutive NaNs
    is > ``limit``.

    Adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30538371/11052174

    :param df_or_series: DataFrame or Series to perform interpolation
        on.
    :param limit: Maximum number of consecutive NaNs to allow. Any
        occurrences of more consecutive NaNs than ``limit`` will have no
        filling performed.
    :param fill_method: Filling method to use, e.g. 'interpolate',
        'bfill', etc.
    :param fill_method_kwargs: Keyword arguments to pass to the
        fill_method, in addition to the given limit.

    :returns: A filled version of the given df_or_series according
        to the given inputs.
    """

    # Keep things simple, ensure we have a DataFrame.
    try:
        df = df_or_series.to_frame()
    except AttributeError:
        df = df_or_series

    # Initialize our mask.
    mask = pd.DataFrame(True, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

    # Get cumulative sums of consecutive NaNs.
    grp = (df.notnull() != df.shift().notnull()).cumsum()

    # Add columns of ones.
    grp['ones'] = 1

    # Loop through columns and update the mask.
    for col in df.columns:

        mask.loc[:, col] = (
                (grp.groupby(col)['ones'].transform('count') <= limit)
                | df[col].notnull()
        )

    # Now, interpolate and use the mask to create NaNs for the larger
    # gaps.
    method = getattr(df, fill_method)
    out = method(limit=limit, **fill_method_kwargs)[mask]

    # Be nice to the caller and return a Series if that's what they
    # provided.
    if isinstance(df_or_series, pd.Series):
        # Return a Series.
        return out.loc[:, out.columns[0]]

    return out
```

Usage:

```py
>>> data_filled = fill_with_hard_limit(data, 5)
>>> data_filled
                         a      b      c   d       e       f       g       h
2014-02-21 14:50:00  123.5  433.5  123.5 NaN     NaN     NaN  2330.3  2330.3
2014-02-21 14:51:00  129.9  523.2  132.3 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:52:00  136.3  536.3  136.3 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:53:00  164.3  464.3  164.3 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:54:00  213.0  413.0  164.3 NaN     NaN  2763.0     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:55:00  164.3  164.3  164.3 NaN     NaN  2142.3     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:56:00  213.0  213.0  164.3 NaN     NaN  2127.3     NaN     NaN
2014-02-21 14:57:00  221.1  221.1  164.3 NaN  2330.3  2330.3     NaN  2777.7
```