# mask only where consecutive nans exceeds x

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was [**answering a question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43079055/2336654) about [**`pandas` `interpolation`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) method.  The OP wanted to use only interpolate where the number of consecutive `np.nan`s was one.  The `limit=1` option for `interpolate` will interpolate the first `np.nan` and stop there.  OP wanted to be able to tell that there were in fact more than one `np.nan` and not even bother with the first one.

I boiled this down to just executing the `interpolate` as is and mask the consecutive `np.nan` after the fact.

The question is: What is a generalized solution that takes a 1-d array `a` and an integer `x` and produces a boolean mask with False in the positions of x or more consecutive `np.nan`

Consider the 1-d array `a`

```
a = np.array([1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1])
```

I'd expect that for `x = 2` the mask would look like this

```
# assume 1 for True and 0 for False 
# a is [  1.  nan  nan  nan   1.  nan   1.   1.  nan  nan   1.   1.]
# mask [  1.   0.   0.   0.   1.   1.   1.   1.   0.   0.   1.   1.]
#                                  ^
#                                  |
#   Notice that this is not masked because there is only one np.nan
```

I'd expect that for `x = 3` the mask would look like this

```
# assume 1 for True and 0 for False 
# a is [  1.  nan  nan  nan   1.  nan   1.   1.  nan  nan   1.   1.]
# mask [  1.   0.   0.   0.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
#                                  ^              ^    ^
#                                  |              |    |
# Notice that this is not masked because there is less than 3 np.nan's
```

I look forward to learning from others ideas ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) for such easy to grasp but hard to "numpyfy" problems! Even though that package might be a bit too heavy for most libraries it allows to write such "python"-like functions without loosing too much speed:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import math

@nb.njit
def mask_nan_if_consecutive(arr, limit):  # I'm not good at function names :(
    result = np.ones_like(arr)
    cnt = 0
    for idx in range(len(arr)):
        if math.isnan(arr[idx]):
            cnt += 1
            # If we just reached the limit we need to backtrack,
            # otherwise just mask current.
            if cnt == limit:
                for subidx in range(idx-limit+1, idx+1):
                    result[subidx] = 0
            elif cnt > limit:
                result[idx] = 0
        else:
            cnt = 0

    return result
```

At least if you worked with pure-python this should be quite easy to understand and it should work:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1])
>>> mask_nan_if_consecutive(a, 1)
array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.])
>>> mask_nan_if_consecutive(a, 2)
array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.])
>>> mask_nan_if_consecutive(a, 3)
array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
>>> mask_nan_if_consecutive(a, 4)
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

But the really nice thing about `@nb.njit`-decorator is, that this function will be fast:

```
a = np.array([1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1])
i = 2

res1 = mask_nan_if_consecutive(a, i)
res2 = mask_knans(a, i)
np.testing.assert_array_equal(res1, res2)

%timeit mask_nan_if_consecutive(a, i)  # 100000 loops, best of 3: 6.03 µs per loop
%timeit mask_knans(a, i)               # 1000 loops, best of 3: 302 µs per loop
```

So for short arrays this is approximatly 50 times faster, even though the difference gets lower it's still faster for longer arrays:

```
a = np.array([1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1]*100000)
i = 2

%timeit mask_nan_if_consecutive(a, i)  # 10 loops, best of 3: 20.9 ms per loop
%timeit mask_knans(a, i)               # 10 loops, best of 3: 154 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I created this generalized solution

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as strided

def mask_knans(a, x):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    k = a.shape[0]

    # I will stride n.  I want to pad with 1 less False than
    # the required number of np.nan's
    n = np.append(np.isnan(a), [False] * (x - 1))

    # prepare the mask and fill it with True
    m = np.empty(k, np.bool8)
    m.fill(True)

    # stride n into a number of columns equal to
    # the required number of np.nan's to mask
    # this is essentially a rolling all operation on isnull
    # also reshape with `[:, None]` in preparation for broadcasting
    # np.where finds the indices where we successfully start
    # x consecutive np.nan's
    s = n.strides[0]
    i = np.where(strided(n, (k + 1 - x, x), (s, s)).all(1))[0][:, None]

    # since I prepped with `[:, None]` when I add `np.arange(x)`
    # I'm including the subsequent indices where the remaining
    # x - 1 np.nan's are
    i = i + np.arange(x)

    # I use `pd.unique` because it doesn't sort and I don't need to sort
    i = pd.unique(i[i < k])

    m[i] = False

    return m
```

---

***w/o comments***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as strided

def mask_knans(a, x):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    k = a.shape[0]
    n = np.append(np.isnan(a), [False] * (x - 1))
    m = np.empty(k, np.bool8)
    m.fill(True)
    s = n.strides[0]
    i = np.where(strided(n, (k + 1 - x, x), (s, s)).all(1))[0][:, None]
    i = i + np.arange(x)
    i = pd.unique(i[i < k])
    m[i] = False
    return m
```

---

***demo***

```
mask_knans(a, 2)

[ True False False False  True  True  True  True False False  True  True]
```

---

```
mask_knans(a, 3)

[ True False False False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
```